# Converting a Functor to an Object of Type function

Tags: c++, templates, parameters, functor, function-object

Say I have this function:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(function<T(const T&, const T&)> op, const T& lhs, const T& rhs) {
    cout << op(lhs, rhs) << endl;
}
```

This is [legal code](http://ideone.com/3Pxtd8):

```
function<int(const int&, const int&)> op = plus<int>();

foo(op, 13, 42);
```

But when I do this:

```
foo(plus<int>(), 13, 42)
```

I get the error:

> No matching function for call to `foo(std::plus<int>, int, int)`

Why can I initialize an object of type `function<int(const int&, const int&)>` from `plus<int>()` but I cannot pass `plus<int>()` into an parameter of type `function<T(const T&, const T&)>`? Is it something having to do with the template?

Comment: Implicit type conversions do not work during template argument deduction.

Comment: @Arunmu I think there are exceptions from that rule: [example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ld8NyDotgjK7B7WT)

Comment: @Arunmu That is the answer cause it works if I remove the template: http://ideone.com/bfjy3p So how do I know the conversion between `plus<int>()` and `function<T(const T&, const T&)>` is implicit?

Comment: @W.F Yes, I think there are exceptions for array to pointer and function to function pointer decay.

Comment: @JonathanMee There is no template deduction happening in your example ( in the comment ). And the constructor of `std::function` is not `explicit`. So it can happiliy construct an function object from the functor (`std::plus`)

Comment: Replacing the template with a generic lambda would work: `auto foo = [](auto op, const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { std::cout << op(lhs, rhs) << '\n'; };`

Comment: Is there a way for me to force the construction other than call it explicitly, like: `foo(function<int(const int&, const int&)>(plus<int>()), 13, 42)`

Comment: You could just use `foo<int>(std::plus<int>{}, 13, 42);`

Comment: @flatmouse Your lambda works simply because it is using `auto`. I can do that in the function too, but I want to force the types to be linked: http://ideone.com/IPMRYe

Comment: @flatmouse Your second comment works because you specify the type of `T` before supplying arguments. That is probably the best plan to be fair.

Comment: If you can use generic functions then that should be best. What do you mean by "force types to be linked"?

Comment: @flatmouse For example if we use the `auto` types I can do this: `foo(plus<double>(), 13, 42)` Which I want to prevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the Standard section 14.8.1.6:

> Implicit conversions (Clause 4) will be performed on a function
>   argument to convert it to the type of the corresponding function
>   parameter if the parameter type contains no template-parameters that
>   participate in template argument deduction.

This does not work in your case because the template parameters have not been provided explicitly. The compiler needs to do a deduction. Thus as per the above, it will not do the implicit conversion from functor to `std::function`.

So, you can do  (As mentioned by @flatmouse in the comment):

`foo<int>(plus<int>(), 13, 42);`

This works because there is no template argument deduction that needs to be performed since all the template parameters are explicitly specified. And as per the above quote from standard, the implicit conversion should work for this.

Comment: Thanks for the quote from the standard, this is an excellent answer. I'll accept shortly...

Comment: Glad to help. Thanks.